# Take a turn or make a turn around something or is it "went around something"

Tags: word-usage

I know that "taking a turn" is only used in one sense "She took a wrong turn", i.e. She went around a wrong turn.(at a turning). Whereas it is "Make a U-turn". But is the use of "take a turn" natural here?

> We all **took a turn** round the cairn, in a clockwise direction as in the tradition, and Tsetan checked the tyres on his vehicle.

Shouldn't it be "we all went around the cairn", and if "turn" has to be used, then "made" should be used with it "we all made a turn around the cairn"?

Comment: Your premises are mostly wrong: "taking a turn" is not _only_ used in the sense you describe, and "she went around a wrong turn" and "make U-turn" are both incorrect. They should be "she **took** (or **made**) a wrong turn" and "make **a** U-turn." As for your actual question, [more context would be useful](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), but I suspect the intended meaning here is that of [**taking turns**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/take-turns) where each person in a group takes an action in order.

Comment: Your context draws on either / both of the senses *We all **had a go / turn** [at driving round the cairn]*, and ***...went** [round the cairn, which would involve **turning** all the way around it]*. Also with overtones of ***went for a spin*** - a short drive, just for the enjoyment of driving (but in *that* sense the turning motion alluded to is the ***vehicle's wheels*** - road wheels *and* steering wheel - rather than the actual route taken). Maybe also an allusion to *taking a turn **on stage*** (to "perform", as a ***show, presentation***, aimed at an ***audience / spectators***).

Comment: So @FumbleFingers is my interpretation is wrong? Did the writer mean "take turns", and not "going around the cairn"? Isn't it just "take turns doing something" or can it be "take a turn at doing something"?

Comment: I don't know if your "interpretation" is wrong. But you're definitely mistaken if you think that ***taking** a turn [[round] somewhere]* only ever implies *in an allotted sequence*. It's a bit dated today, but still perfectly grammatical to say *Let's take a turn along the esplanade (seafront walkway)*. That usage implies nothing about allotted sequences, but it *does* often imply "putting on a show", "strutting your stuff" (the fact that there will be ***observers*** is usually central to that usage).

Comment: I would link *turn* in this example to *tour*, a cognate word (and incidentally the French equivalent of *turn* in many of its senses).  We all walked around the cairn to have a good look at it, and/or to stretch our legs.

Comment: Both *taking my turn in the competition* and *taking a turn for the worse* are normal expressions, and they imply nothing about direction. (In short, it's simply not true that there is only one sense of the phrase.)